# Left join and matching dates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to match a date from my `dimdate` table to the dates in my sales table. The reason for using the `left join` is so that we see all dates between `2017-10-05` to `2017-10-10` and the  `SSRS` matrix displays a column for each date, even if it doesn't have any data.

This is an example query:

```
declare @table table
(
    fname varchar(20),
    Sales int,
    SaleDate date,
    LastSale date
)

insert into @table
select 'John', 1, '2017/10/08', '2017/10/10'
union
select 'John', 3, '2017/10/09', '2017/10/10'
union
select 'John', 5, '2017/10/10', '2017/10/10'
union
select 'Mary', 1, '2017/10/06', '2017/10/08'
union
select 'Mary', 3, '2017/10/07', '2017/10/08'
union
select 'Mary', 5, '2017/10/08', '2017/10/08'
union
select 'Carl', 10, '2017/10/07', '2017/10/09'
union
select 'Carl', 13, '2017/10/08', '2017/10/09'
union
select 'Carl', 32, '2017/10/09', '2017/10/09'


select dim.fulldatealternatekey as 'fulldate', fname, sales, t.SaleDate
from dimdate dim left join @table t
on dim.fulldatealternatekey = t.SaleDate
where FullDateAlternateKey between '2017-10-05' and '2017-10-10'
and LastSale < '2017-10-10'
```

The issue is that nobody has '10-05-2017' so `fname` is null, which screws up the report because it shows an extra line.

The other issue is that I don't want to see anyone whose `lastsale` is *2017-10-10*, but as soon as I uncomment `and LastSale < '2017-10-10'` it becomes an `inner join` and I don't see either *2017-10-05* or *2017-10-10*.

The ideal output should be:

```
fulldate     fname   sales    SaleDate
2017-10-05   Carl    NULL     NULL
2017-10-06   Carl    NULL     NULL
2017-10-07   Carl    10       2017-10-07
2017-10-08   Carl    13       2017-10-08
2017-10-09   Carl    32       2017-10-09
2017-10-10   Carl    NULL     NULL
2017-10-05   Mary    NULL     NULL
2017-10-06   Mary    1        2017-10-06
2017-10-07   Mary    3        2017-10-07
2017-10-08   Mary    5        2017-10-08
2017-10-09   Mary    NULL     NULL
2017-10-10   Mary    NULL     NULL
```

I only need that 1 `fname` should include all `fulldate`s from `2017-10-05` to `2017-10-10`, since this is so that SSRS shows all dates, so something like this is also great:

```
fulldate     fname   sales   SaleDate
2017-10-05    Carl   NULL    NULL        -- It can be Carl or Mary, doesn't matter
2017-10-07    Carl   10      2017-10-07
2017-10-08    Carl   13      2017-10-08
2017-10-09    Carl   32      2017-10-09
2017-10-06    Mary   12      2017-10-06
2017-10-07    Mary   32      2017-10-07
2017-10-08    Mary   52      2017-10-08
2017-10-10    Mary   NULL    NULL        -- It can be Carl or Mary, doesn't matter
```

I assume I can create a temp table of all dates and update that table with one row, and then somehow use a union and exclude that row, but I know there has to be another way.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide structure and simple data of your dimdate table

Answer (score 0):

For your lastDate problem change condition from WHERE to JOIN criteria like below

```
select dim.fulldatealternatekey as 'fulldate', fname, sales, t.SaleDate
from dimdate dim left join @table t
on dim.fulldatealternatekey = t.SaleDate and LastSale < '2017-10-10'
where FullDateAlternateKey between '2017-10-05' and '2017-10-10'
```

for your final output, query should be

```
select 
  dim.fulldatealternatekey as 'fulldate', 
  coalesce(fname, (SELECT TOP 1 fname from @table)) as fname,
  sales, 
  t.SaleDate
from dimdate dim left join @table t
   on dim.fulldatealternatekey = t.SaleDate and LastSale < '2017-10-10'
where FullDateAlternateKey between '2017-10-05' and '2017-10-10'
order by dim.fulldatealternatekey asc
```